# GAE ndb and query quota limits

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

I have a GAE app that stores thousands of questions in ndb, and then retrieve some randomly and present them to the user as a test

The problem:
- I need to query questions in a random order to make sure the questions are different from test to test
- GAE ndb query doesn't seem to accept RAND() operation, so instead, I fetch all questions, shuffle the returned list, splice it and return the result

The problem: even if the user needs only 10 questions, all questions that meet the conditions will be fetched (which may be thousands), and this means i will be out of free quota quickly

Any ideas?

Comment: create a single entity which holds a list of questions. A list of NDB question keys. NDB will cache this entity and its easy to select the random keys, using a get_multi.

Comment: But then I won't be able to fetch with conditions like (WHERE subject IN list) because the saved keys have no idea what other projections are unless I fetch them

Comment: Please update your question to make it clear. Because you said in your question: "all thousands questions will be fetched".

Comment: There are lots of questions on this topic in SO, I suggest you have a read of few of them, to see the various different approaches.  Some will probably match your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to store each question with an explicit sequential integer ID.
To select questions at random, generate a list of numbers between 0 and your current number of questions, and call `ndb.get_multi` to get the questions.

The tricky part is incrementing the counter, without holes, each time you insert a new question. The [sharded counter tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters) might help.

Comment: Again, the IDs of the resulted random list cannot be checked for properties of the associated question... for example, if the user wants questions regarding subject A, the resulted IDs may not be of subject A... I need to check the IDs subject before getting a random list of these IDs which mean query all IDs, which again, cause the same problem

Comment: Agreed. You'd need to make the subject an ancestor of the question, with one counter for each subject, which cannot work if one question may have several subjects.

Comment: Actually, I got an idea from your idea... ID must be unique for a question, and thus different ancestors (or subjects) can have the same id of a question that has different subjects... it is a long way to go and looks even more complicated... I wish there was an easier way to just randomize answers from gql...
Any way, thanks a lot for your help